# May I alter SERVER for foreign table?

Tags: postgresql, postgres-fdw

According to the [DOC](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-alterforeigntable.html) I can not do that. But fully recreate table force me to do huge work instead of simple:

```
ALTER FOREIGN TABLE table_name ALTER SERVER new_server_name;
```

Answer (score 6):

List your foreign data servers and note it oid:

```
select oid, * from pg_foreign_server
```

Find your foreign table:

```
select oid, * from pg_class where relkind = 'f'
```

Then modify system catalog `pg_foreign_table` like:

```
update pg_foreign_table set ftserver = 11573931 where ftserver = 11573932 -- and ftrelid = YOUR_OID_RELID_FROM_PG_CLASS
```

Answer (score 2):

In postgres 12 this command worked fine in order to change the server IP address that was used for foreign DB wrapper

```
alter  server  YOUR_SERVER_NAME  options (set  host 'XX.XXX.XX.X');
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't change server using this way, because it will not update dependency table pg_depend and cause many problems later.